# 'Text on Symbols' vector legend how to call 'Set Labels from Expression...' or similar from PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, legend

I am trying to programmatically set vector legend **Text on Symbols** with PyQGIS. This can be manually performed from **Layer Properties -> Legend -> Text on Symbols -> Set Labels from Expression...** e.g. using an attribute `"MAP_SYMBOL"`, refer screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Layer Properties -> Legend]

The relevant C++ gui widget is [QgsVectorLayerLegendWidget](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgsvectorlayerlegendwidget_8cpp_source.html)

But so far I have been unsuccessful replicating the logic that starts with `QgsVectorLayerLegendWidget::labelsFromExpression()` in PyQGIS, is this even possible or realistic? There is a lot going on there to apply the expression that does not appear to be exposed via the PyQGIS bindings.

There are some tantalizing PyQGIS-accessible classes e.g. [QgsLegendSymbolItem](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsLegendSymbolItem.html) and [QgsDefaultVectorLayerLegend](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDefaultVectorLayerLegend.html) but I can't see how to modify the Text on Symbols and then successfully apply these classes to the vector layer which is not straightforward based on the C++ code.

Related: [Adding text on symbols using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/401600)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic example which you can test. This is assuming you want to use the field "MAP_SYMBOL" as per your question as the expression to set the text on symbol.

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

# Retrieve the current symbol node text format
tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()
model = tree_view.layerTreeModel()
root = model.rootGroup()
ltl = root.findLayer(lyr)
nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(ltl)
text_format = nodes[0].textOnSymbolTextFormat()

content = {}
context = QgsRenderContext.fromMapSettings(canvas.mapSettings())
# Set your expression here
expr = QgsExpression("MAP_SYMBOL")
expr.prepare(context.expressionContext())

r = lyr.renderer().clone()

r.startRender(context, lyr.fields())

for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    context.expressionContext().setFeature(f)
    keys = set(r.legendKeysForFeature(f, context))
    for key in keys:
        if key in content:
            continue
        label = expr.evaluate(context.expressionContext())
        if label:
            content[key] = label

r.stopRender(context)

legend = QgsDefaultVectorLayerLegend(lyr)
legend.setTextOnSymbolEnabled(True)
legend.setTextOnSymbolContent(content)
legend.setTextOnSymbolTextFormat(text_format)
lyr.setLegend(legend)
legend.itemsChanged.emit()
```

This bit of code is basically put together from bits picked out of the [QgsVectorLayerLegendWidget](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgsvectorlayerlegendwidget_8cpp_source.html) C++ source code, primarily the methods:  `QgsVectorLayerLegendWidget::labelsFromExpression()` and `QgsVectorLayerLegendWidget::applyToLayer()`.

As an example, I tested on a soil layer with a categorized renderer, classified with the "MAPUNIT" field.

With the script above modified only by changing the line which declares the expression to:

```py
expr = QgsExpression("SOIL_TYPE")
```

The result after running the code was:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to read the existing legend text format (if exists) and reuse that with legend.setTextOnSymbolTextFormat()? Otherwise I suppose could use the layer Labels format as a default? My actual use case for this is trimming unused categories from a QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer which then needs the Text on Symbols to be updated. Amazing answer, thank you.

Comment: @Jared P, no worries. The best way I found to get the existing legend symbol nodes' text format is to access the nodes via the `QgsLayerTreeModel.layerLegendNodes()` method, then call `textOnSymbolTextFormat()` on the the first node. That should work well enough for your use case. I have updated my answer. Let me know how it goes. Cheers

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Jared P, great! No problem :-)